# Add header title above the query result in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can I add heading title for each query?

I want to display it as a report with a heading above the query result of the table.

Something like this

```
         HEADING
_____________________________
Alexis M. Smith | PHP 140,500
Johnny K. Black | PHP  50,000
James P. Blonde | PHP  30,000
```

I am using sql server management 2012 Studio and vb.net 2010
I don't have Business Intelligence to create a report from the sql server to vb.net 2010

Comment: You don't have to do this in the query. Just do it in the report.

Comment: Show us the query you have and the data you're getting. Formatting is normally a reporting type function.

Comment: SQL Server just gives you the raw data, how you present it depends on the language/application you are using.

Comment: You need to use a reporting tool, e.g.  SQL Server **Reporting Services**, or Crystal Reports or something like this.

Comment: There is nothing called header, all in COLUMNS and  ROWS.

Comment: the fact that I don't have the business intelligence to create a report from visual studio :(, I am using sql server managment 2012, vb.net 2010

Comment: What do you view your report in? SSMS? Or do you copy / paste into Excel?

Answer (score 4):

You may can't add header in your query result in SQL-Server and show the result in your application..

But if you are asking to show the result in SQL-Server only, then this might help you..

```
--You have to add one select query before your actual query like this.
select '' as 'Your Heading Here' where 1!=1
select * from your_table
```

Comment: What about a subheader? is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select b.a  AS Heading
  FROM
    ( Select Concat('Mr. Xyz', ' |  ', 'PHP' , ' | ' , '50000') AS a
    ) B
```

This is the closest I could think.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCatignani