# Remove the leftmost row-numbering column in a SSMS query result

Tags: sql-server, ssms

By default, every query result is displayed with a row-numbering column to its left:
[image]

How can it be removed?

Comment: why do you want that removed?

Comment: Because I'd like to use a "header query" (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39943445/3002584)) for teaching purposes, and this column prevents the header text to be left-aligned. Kind of pedantic, but that's what I need.

Comment: Do you need for your result set to return as a grid? If you switch to "results to text" (CTRL-T by default, I believe) that column doesn't show...

Comment: well, it's not a `column` but how is it not left aligned? Your "header query" will be stored in column 1, right above column 1 of your second statement

Comment: I need the header text to start from the leftmost side, so it would have a look of a header, and not as a kind of a weird table.

Comment: If you are using SSMS to display results as part of a teaching situation you would be doing your audience a disservice by changing the UI that you are trying to show them how to use. When they go to use it themselves I envision us getting questions about a new "feature". :D

Answer (score 1):

Save the results to text or to a text file and there will be no row numbers
[image]