# How to add additional title line in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to add additional title lines to my sql query like this:

```
+--------+-----------------------------+
|        |        Total Sales          |
+--------+-----------------------------+
  Client   This_month   Previous_month 
  111      230           190         
  222                    80
```

Is this possible?

```
Select Client, This_month, Previous_month FROM table1
```

Comment: explain bit more.

Comment: what's the current query ..?

Comment: Select Client, This_month, Previous_month FROM table1

Comment: Which line you mean to add? `Total Sales`?

Comment: I know that I can add additional table with the additional title lines as field values and union them with the original query, but is it possible to do without an additional table?

Comment: Ideally I would need the two dashed lines and Total Sales.

Comment: Something like this ? `SELECT '','Total' AS '','Sales' AS '' UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Client','This_Month','Previous_month' UNION ALL Select Client, This_month, Previous_month FROM table1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941554/add-header-title-above-the-query-result-in-sql-server

Comment: That example is for SQL Server. It doesn't seem to work on MySQL.

Comment: Handle issues of data display in your application code

Answer (score 0):

I think what the OP wants is a Column(s) with alias:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(This_month, ',', previous_month) AS 'Total Sales' FROM <table> WHERE <xyz>
```

I am just not sure how to display the original column names

[mysql Alias](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php)