# How to include header text as the first row in SQL generated Excel report?

Tags: sql, oracle, text, header, union

I have a requirement to generate excel report as follows.

My query is :

```
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name
from table AA
union
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name
from table BB
union
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name
from table CC;
```

This perfectly gives me the columns with the heading.

But I need the Header text (`" User Generated .......`) to be displayed on the first row (above the column heading)

Any inputs or suggestions ???

[sample expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtyXz.png)

Comment: see this question = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941554/add-header-title-above-the-query-result-in-sql-server

Comment: You can't have anything above a header in SQL because they don't work the same way as excel. SQL is also not the most appropriate tool to do this. If I were you, I would include `current_date as rundate`  in the `select` so you have rundate as an additional column  in your output. Then when you dump that into excel, have a template where you have "User Generated Reports as of" text in some cell, then use any cell in the rundate column to concatenate the text above with the rundate. You can then hide the rundate column.

Answer (score 0):

After exporting SQL to Excel, you can execute Excel Micro to add desired row and data.
Example :- Below micro insert a row at top [pushes down all rows by one row down]. It will merge A1 to H1 cells and write "User Generated Report Date:- " {Today's Date} in cell A1

```
       Sub AddCustomRow()
          Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
          Worksheets("Sqliteman Export").Range("A1:H1").Merge
          Range("A1").Value = "User Generated Report Date:- " & Date
       End Sub
```

I am attaching image to show you result of micro

[image]

Very short help on how to create Excel Micro -
Open exported data in excel. View Menu > Micro > Provide Micro Name > Create
Paste Micro given in above answer. Save. F5 to execute micro.
Check excel sheet for result.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name from
(select null as emp_id, 'User generated report as of '|| to_char(sysdate,'dd/Mon/yyyy') as emp_name, null as dept_name, 1 as val from dual
union
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name, 2 as val
from table AA
union
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name, 3 as val
from table BB
union
select emp_id, emp_name, dept_name, 4 as val
from table CC) order by val;
```

Explination:

1. Selected the headed default value and date in dual and used as union in the query
2. Created a dummy value for each union as `val` 1,2,3 and 4 and used it in `order by clause` so that the header comes at the top